# String error in my python api wrapper class

Tags: python, api, wrapper

I'm writing an API wrapper to a couple of different web services.

I have a method that has an article url, and I want to extract text from it using alchemyapi.

```
def extractText(self):
    #All Extract Text Methods ---------------------------------------------------------//
    #Extract page text from a web URL (ignoring navigation links, ads, etc.).
    if self.alchemyapi == True:
        self.full_text = self.alchemyObj.URLGetText(self.article_link)
```

which goes to the following code in the python wrapper

```
def URLGetText(self, url, textParams=None):
    self.CheckURL(url)
    if textParams == None:
      textParams = AlchemyAPI_TextParams()
    textParams.setUrl(url)
    return self.GetRequest("URLGetText", "url", textParams)

def GetRequest(self, apiCall, apiPrefix, paramObject):
    endpoint = 'http://' + self._hostPrefix + '.alchemyapi.com/calls/' + apiPrefix + '/' + apiCall
    endpoint += '?apikey=' + self._apiKey + paramObject.getParameterString()
    handle = urllib.urlopen(endpoint)
    result = handle.read()
    handle.close()
    xpathQuery = '/results/status'
    nodes = etree.fromstring(result).xpath(xpathQuery)
    if nodes[0].text != "OK":
      raise 'Error making API call.'
    return result
```

However I get this error ---

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "text_proc.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.alchemyObj.loadAPIKey("api_key.txt");    
  File "text_proc.py", line 115, in extractText
    if self.alchemyapi == True:
  File "/Users/Diesel/Desktop/AlchemyAPI.py", line 502, in URLGetText
    return self.GetRequest("URLGetText", "url", textParams)
  File "/Users/Diesel/Desktop/AlchemyAPI.py", line 618, in GetRequest
    raise 'Error making API call.'
```

I know I'm somehow passing the url string to the api wrapper in a faulty format, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you *please* fix the intendations? It's quite important how you do them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information provided is not actually very helpful to diagnose or solve the problem. Have you considered taking a look at the response from the server? You might inspect a complete traffic log using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Additionally, the SDK provided by Alchemy doesn't seem to be of - cough, cough - the greatest quality. Since it really consists only of around 600 lines of source code, I'd consider writing a shorter, more robust / pythonic / whatever SDK.

I might also add that right now, even the on-site demo at the Alchemy web site is failing, so maybe your problem is related to that. I really suggest taking a look at the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You should raise Exception or a subclass thereof, instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because your function `GetRequest()` raising a string as an exception:

```
if nodes[0].text != "OK":
  raise 'Error making API call.'
```

If that's not what you want, you have two options:

1. You can have the function `return` the string or `None`, or
2. You can pass the error message to a real subclass of `Exception` (as suggested by **knutin**)

In either case, if you are assigning that return value to a variable, you can handle it accordingly.  Here is an example:

**Option 1**
Let's assume you decide to have `GetRequest()` return `None`:

```
def URLGetText(self, url, textParams=None):
    self.CheckURL(url)
    if textParams == None:
        textParams = AlchemyAPI_TextParams()
    textParams.setUrl(url)

    # Capture the value of GetRequest() before returning it
    retval = self.GetRequest("URLGetText", "url", textParams)
    if retval is None:
        print 'Error making API call.' # print the error but still return 

    return retval 

def GetRequest(self, apiCall, apiPrefix, paramObject):
    # ...
    if nodes[0].text != "OK":
      return None
    return result
```

This option is a little ambiguous. How do you know that it was really an error, or the return value truly was `None`?

**Option 2**
This is probably the better way to do it:

First create an subclass of `Exception`:

```
class GetRequestError(Exception):
    """Error returned from GetRequest()"""
    pass
```

Then raise it in GetRequest()`:

```
def URLGetText(self, url, textParams=None):
    self.CheckURL(url)
    if textParams == None:
      textParams = AlchemyAPI_TextParams()
    textParams.setUrl(url)

    # Attempt to get a legit return value & handle errors
    try:
        retval = self.GetRequest(apiCall, apiPrefix, paramObject)
    except GetRequestError as err:
        print err # prints 'Error making API call.'
        # handle the error here
        retval = None

    return retval

def GetRequest(self, apiCall, apiPrefix, paramObject):
    # ...
    if nodes[0].text != "OK":
      raise GetRequestError('Error making API call.')
    return result
```

This way you're raising a legitimate error when GetRequest() doesn't return the desired result, and then you can handle the error using a `try..except` block and optionally print the error, stop the program there, or keep going (which is what I think you want to do based on your question).

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  Undo! Undo!

Comment: LOL -- Thanks for the design pattern help !  I'm going to take Jim's advice and just make a small wrapper class for my module.

Comment: Hey all I've scrapped using AlchemyAPI's API and just wrote my own ... no problems now ... go figure...

Answer (score 0):

This is Shaun from AlchemyAPI.  We just posted a new version of the python SDK that raises exceptions properly.  You can get it here http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/.

If you have any other feedback about the SDK, please message me.  Thanks for using our NLP service.